# Not able to get content of Notes from Facebook in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the content of Notes from Facebook in my app. I am using Facebook API version V2.0.

I have tried both Graph API and FQL query to get contents of Notes, but it is giving error that "**notes API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher**".

Please help me to solve the problem.

Here is the code using Graph API, I have already authenticated using "user_notes"

```
- (void) makeRequestForUserNotes {

      [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/notes" 
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, 
                                                id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {

             // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
             NSLog(@"user Notes Response: %@", result);

             // read data value from result
             NSMutableArray *dataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

             dataArr = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

             if([dataArr count] != 0) {
                 // get value from contents
             }

        } else {

            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // Check out our error handling guide: 
            // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);   
        }

    }];

 }
```

Here giving directly error after execution as as "**notes API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher**".

Comment: It is easier to help if you show us the code you attempted, even if it doesn't work. Else question should state that you expect answers to be perfectly working code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in the error message itself: This is no longer working with the Graph API v2.0 **(and no, there's no workaround!)**.

See the [API Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api)

> `/me/notes` is no longer available, along with the `user_notes` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use the latest version of FB SDK  this method is no longer available in Graph API and its deprecated ,please check this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/

Thanks